# How to recover partitions 'cleaned' by DiskPart, which Windows Explorer does not show?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery

I've been through tough times recovering the partitions i accidentally deleted while creating 'Unallocated Space' to install Windows 8.1 alongside Windows 10.

But I'm in a complex situation now.

While I was cleaning the drive (I wanted to install win 8.1 to) by Diskpart from the cmd, the process didn't complete and rather i got an error, after that i realized that the diskpart tool was on its way to wipe the whole disk, but failed when it reached the 'C' drive where my os is installed.

After searching the internet, some website suggested me to use MiniTool partition manager's partition recovery tool. I downloaded the software and to my surprise found the partition manager showing that my lost disks were not empty, rather they became 'unlabelled' and had no labels like D: or E; (the two concerned local disks i wiped out).

Here are some screenshots that clarify my situation.

[image]

At the top right corner it can be seen that the concerned drives are not empty (as this tool is showing).

But the windows disk manager (diskmgmt.msc) has some different tale to tell. It shows those two volumes as unlabeled and 100% empty. (see screenshot below)

[image]

And here the Windows Explorer doesn't show those two volumes

[image]

Please help me out! All my important data were there in those two volumes and the loss is huge for me.

Comment: Probably some data have been overwritten, but you can also try to use some third party software (such as MiniTool Power Data Recovery) to see whether it can find your data.
https://www.powerdatarecovery.com/recover-lost-file-by-diskpart-clean.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried giving letters to the 2 volumes in minitool partition wizard? If you are unable to give them letters, you may need to recover data use minitool's data recovery software at first, and then delete those volumes.

Comment: Your solution worked like magic, in the windows disk management console (diskmgmt.msc), I assigned path letters to the drives and all of a sudden they were accessible. No format, no recovery, nothing was required.